# Model properties not displaying with MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I just started learning ASP.NET MVC4 today. After reading tutorials, downloading VS 2012, and creating my first MVC4 app, my model data isn't displaying on the web page.

**Model**

```
namespace DistributorManagement.Models
{
    public class Vaporizer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }    
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class VaporizerController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Vaporizer vaporizer = new Vaporizer();
        vaporizer.Id = 1;
        vaporizer.Manufacturer = "Acme";

        return View(vaporizer);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model DistributorManagement.Models.Vaporizer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Vaporizer";
}

<h2>Snuh</h2>

<label>Vaporizer ID</label>
@Html.Display(Model.Id.ToString())
<br />
<label>Manufacturer</label>
@Html.Display(Model.Manufacturer)
```

**The Web Page**

[image]

I tried a few variations of displaying the properties of a Vaporizer, but nothing ever displays on the web page. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use the HtmlHelper extension method "Display" to display the string.
This method takes "An expression that identifies the object that contains the properties to display" as a string parameter, and not a string to actually display.

cf : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee310174.aspx

In your case you should just display the string like this :

```
<label>Vaporizer ID</label>
@Model.Id
<br />
<label>Manufacturer</label>
@Model.Manufacturer
```

And should work fine !

Comment: Ah... that worked! All I had to do was this: @Model.Id, right in the HTML. Thanks!